# What does a downward-pointing "$\rightarrowtail$" sign mean?

Tags: notation

Can anyone please tell me what this sign stand for?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the sign is standard.

Comment: My guess would be “strictly decreasing”, but I’ve never seen that symbol used before.

Comment: I also have not seen it earlier. I can not search it in google becuase that sign can not be typed.@Joe

Comment: Can you show us more of the context it is used in?

Comment: Look for the first ocurrence of the symbol in the text. It should be defined there.

Comment: I have got this question only@JackozeeHakkiuz

Comment: @sani Where did you get it from?

Comment: Is the source a textbook, and if so, does can you search the book for where it defines “strictly decreasing”? Or is the source an assignment, and if so, has the professor used that symbol in the lecture notes?

Comment: Which topic is this? Or which class is this exercise taken from?

Comment: Worth remarking that "strictly decreasing" certainly does imply one-to-one, so I expect that is a good guess.

Comment: For anyone curious, the symbol is a downward version of the \rightarrowtail symbol $\rightarrowtail$ (similarly for left arrow). It can be generated by use of the \rotatebox command in the graphicx package.